# Refactoring elisp code that generates files

Tags: emacs, refactoring, elisp

I wrote a simple emacs module that generates standard templates that I use for my blog's static site generator.

```lisp
(defun hakyll-site-location ()
  "Return the location of the Hakyll files."
  "~/Sites/hblog/")

(defun hakyll-new-post (title tags)
  "Create a new Hakyll post for today with TITLE and TAGS."
  (interactive "sTitle: \nsTags: ")
  (let ((file-name (hakyll-post-title title)))
    (set-buffer (get-buffer-create file-name))
    (markdown-mode)
    (insert
     (format "---\ntitle: %s\ntags: %s\ndescription: \n---\n\n" title tags))
    (write-file
     (expand-file-name file-name (concat (hakyll-site-location) "posts")))
    (switch-to-buffer file-name)))

(defun hakyll-new-note (title)
  "Create a new Note with TITLE."
  (interactive "sTitle: ")
  (let ((file-name (hakyll-note-title title)))
    (set-buffer (get-buffer-create file-name))
    (markdown-mode)
    (insert (format "---\ntitle: %s\ndescription: \n---\n\n" title))
    (write-file
     (expand-file-name file-name (concat (hakyll-site-location) "notes")))
    (switch-to-buffer file-name)))

(defun hakyll-post-title (title)
  "Return a file name based on TITLE for the post."
  (concat
   (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")
   "-"
   (replace-regexp-in-string " " "-" (downcase title))
   ".markdown"))

(defun hakyll-note-title (title)
  "Return a file name based on TITLE for the note."
  (concat
   (replace-regexp-in-string " " "-" (downcase title))
   ".markdown"))
```

Now, this works, but it could do with DRYing up a little bit, but I don't know enough elisp to do it myself.

- `hakyll-new-post` and `hakyll-new-note` are very similar and could do with DRYing up, but I'm not sure how to pass the correct parameter to any refactored function
- I'm hard coding `hakyll-site-location`. Is there any way that I can request for and store a configuration in my emacs dotfiles?

Any help or pointers to documentation are welcome.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code review.  Perhaps it is better on Code Review (or Programmers?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code. I can't guarantee that it works, but if it was working before,
it should probably work now.

```
(defvar hakyll-site-location "~/Sites/hblog/"
  "Return the location of the Hakyll files.")

(defun hakyll-new-post (title tags)
  "Create a new Hakyll post for today with TITLE and TAGS."
  (interactive "sTitle: \nsTags: ")
  (hakyll-do-write
   (format "%s/posts/%s-%s.markdown"
           hakyll-site-location
           (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")
           (replace-regexp-in-string " " "-" (downcase title)))
   (format "---\ntitle: %s\ntags: %s\ndescription: \n---\n\n"
           title
           tags)))

(defun hakyll-new-note (title)
  "Create a new Note with TITLE."
  (interactive "sTitle: ")
  (hakyll-do-write
   (format "%s/notes/%s.markdown"
           hakyll-site-location
           (replace-regexp-in-string " " "-" (downcase title)))
   (format "---\ntitle: %s\ndescription: \n---\n\n" title)))

(defun hakyll-do-write (file-name str)
  (find-file file-name)
  (insert str)
  (save-buffer))
```

You can set the location with `(setq hakyll-site-location "~/Sites/")` in a dotfile.
You can even change `defvar` to `defcustom` and use customize to set the location.

Comment: Thanks for that; also for `defcustom`, I didn't know about that.

Comment: You've made a bug with your edit: now notes and posts are doubly included

Comment: D'oh! You're quite right; I didn't see it in the format string. But I've corrected it again so that notes don't go in `.../notes/notes/...`.

Comment: Puzzling. It creates the file with the contents correctly, and switches to the buffer. But the buffer is empty and when I go to revert the file to saved it says it's not associated with any buffer.

Comment: I've made an edit. See if this works.